# the word confer in an official academic letter

Tags: academia

I am wondering is this the right way to use confer in a sentence which is part of an official academic letter.

<'degree title'> conferred on <'student name'> by <'the dept., college, university'> on<'data of the award'>.

Example:

This is to further acknowledge that Master of Science in Information Systems was conferred on Ms.Sarah by the Department of Information Systems, College of Computer and Information Sciences, King University, on 1st of July 2011.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in the Academia Stack Exchange.

Comment: @HotLicks This has nothing to do with academia.  It's a question about the usage of the word *confer*, which has 500 years of use in the meaning of bestow or grant honors, titles, and degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found in a very short research is that it is correct, but not as formal as you may wish.  The more formal version would be **upon** rather than on.

> **confer something (up)on someone**
>   to grant something, such as an academic degree, to someone, usually in a ceremony. (Upon is more formal than on.) The university conferred an honorary degree upon her. They conferred degrees on 300 graduates this year.

I found it [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/confer+on).